# Can't run tests provided in Slim Framework

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit, slim, netbeans-8

I'm trying to make a simple rest client for my android app. I would like to do than in TDD way, but for that I need simple working configuration for all actions (GET, POST, and so on). After some struggling I was able to make test work with get requests. Unfortunately with Post routes things didn't go well. When testing (netbeans 8.0.2 + phpunit) on local server (xampp 5.6.3) all I get is 404 error. Same thing if I run method being tested with Advanced Rest Client Application (chrome extension). When I send my rest files to live hosting then method in question works as it should.

After searching for some days (read about everything with 404 errors on Slim Framework) I decided to start with something which should work right of the box. Slim framework comes with simple demo app and some tests. Here I have another error which prevents start of tests: 
Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Middleware' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\local\codeguy-Slim-04958a1\tests\MiddlewareTest.php on line 3

As far I can tell I have something wrong with my xampp server but I don't have any more ideas how to fix this. So If somebody could show me correct way to setup Netbeans, Xampp, Slim and phpunit(I'm running it from IDE (ALT + F6)) then I would be able to build my rest api on top of that.

Comment: Would you add into the question: how did you install Slim? How are you running PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was wrong with my tests and with test provided with framework. I didn't know that I had to set bootstrap.php file in Project configuration of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following, maybe it might suggest a different route to try?

```
git clone https://github.com/codeguy/Slim.git
cd Slim
// Edit composer.json to include "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*"
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

A few tests failed for me, surprisingly - so that would need digging into. But all classes were found.

Everything should work though, as the project [seems to be building OK over on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/codeguy/Slim).

Comment: From what I can see commands you used are for linux ?
Could you provide ones for Win 7 ?

Comment: @Gwynnbleid1: I don't use Windows, but most of them will stay the same. Installing Composer [is here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows) and I expect PHPUnit is a batch file, e.g. `.\vendor\bin\phpunit.bat`. You'll need to install Git of course. If Windows proves awkward, then you can always use Vagrant to do this on Linux.